# Django custom user model with unique_together on the email

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a custom User model in my Django app, the problem is I get an error saying email must be unique (fair enough!), however, I need `email` and `company` together to be unique, as I may have the same email but registered to a different company.

I get the following error:

```
ERRORS:
site.SiteUser: (auth.E003) 'SiteUser.email' must be unique because it is named as the 'USERNAME_FIELD'.
```

Here is my model:

```
class SiteUser(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    objects = SiteUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('company', 'email',)
```

Comment: why are you using `USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'`

Comment: If you're using email as the username field, how are people going to log in/etc. if the emails are not unique?

Comment: @Munro Please do let me know if did get any solution for this problem because I am also facing the same situation.

Answer (score 11):

You're missing the `unique=True` in your email field definition.
The filed that is used in the `USERNAME_FIELD` should have this argument as explained in the [django doc on USERNAME_FIELD](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.USERNAME_FIELD).

It should be like this:

```
email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
```

Answer (score 8):

Add `auth.E003` to the [`SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#silenced-system-checks) setting.  This will allow `manage.py` to run.  And I think you should add [`W004`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/checks/#auth) warning to this list too:

```
SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS = ['auth.E003', 'auth.W004']
```